# Azure B2B with SharePoint Online and Yammer

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, yammer

I have a scenario that I am hoping someone can assist me with. I have a requirement to build an extranet in SharePoint Online (Office 365).

We have a main Office 365 Tenant. There are 15 member organisations that need access and these DO NOT have Office 365. on premise only.

So I can use Azure B2B to grant access to SharePoint Sites no problems. I need the social aspect and Yammer Fits PERFECTLY but identities are separate.

I can create and External Yammer Network and invite users but obviously these are a separate set of credentials to that of Azure AD.

Has anyone done such a thing and is there a way to grant Azure B2B users access to an external Yammer network?

Comment: This is not really a programming question so is off-topic for the site and will probably be closed by moderators. At this moment, there isn't explicit Azure B2B support, but I think the Yammer product team would be interested in hearing about your request. The yammer.uservoice.com site is one place to post, but you can also open a Premier support case.

Comment: I was told to post here by the Azure Support Twitter handle?

Answer (score -1):

Yammer should allow you to sync with your Azure Active Directory. This should allow users to have the same logins.

Here is some information I found on this matter:

https://products.office.com/en-gb/yammer/yammer-network-administration

Comment: Yeah it will for the main tenant,but there are 15 member orgs all having their own Active Directory on premise. Azure B2B needs to be used to give them access to the main tenant as they are not part of that AD. This is fine for SharePoint. What I am trying to work out is how can Azure B2B be used to acess a Yammer external network also....This would mean that external users to the tenant can access both with the same credentials.